# How should I handle multiple strokes on GestureOverlayView?

Tags: android, gesture, stroke

I need to handle multiple strokes on gestureOverlayView by using ongestureListener handler, which is implemented by 4 functions: `ongestureStarted(..)`, `ongestureEnded(..)`, etc.

I used this in xml file:
`android:gestureStrokeType="multiple"`. 
It's taking multiple strokes if we write little fast, but I want to handle its disappearance by myself.

Can any one help in this regard?

Comment: What do you mean you want to handle its disappearance?  Do you want to hide individual gestures? Or control the length of time before it fades out?

Comment: i need to control the length of time before its fading

Answer (score 1):

If you want to control the length of time that gestures remain visible, you should look into these 2 XML attributes from the [documentation for GestureOverlayView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/gesture/GestureOverlayView.html):

`android:fadeOffset`: Time, in milliseconds, to wait before the gesture fades out after the user is done drawing it.

`android:fadeDuration`: Duration, in milliseconds, of the fade out effect after the user is done drawing a gesture.